# Flutter: Using both Pan and Scale gestures together?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I am creating a drawing canvas with flutter for which I want to use both scale (for zooming, panning and rotating) and Pan (for drawing with fingers) gestures but flutter doesn't allow that since Scale is a superset of Pan. Is there any workaround for this?

I tried to create my own custom gesture recognizer for detecting the number of pointers on the screen so that if two pointers come in contact with the screen within a short interval of time(let's say 1 second) Scale takes over otherwise pan starts working with the 1st pointer that touched the screen. I am using [matrix_gesture_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/matrix_gesture_detector) package for doing the scaling part.

Here is my code for the custom gesture recognizer

```
class ScaleAndPanRecognizer extends OneSequenceGestureRecognizer {
  var manager = GestureArenaManager();
  final Function onPanDown;
  final Function onPanUpdate;
  final Function onPanEnd;
  ScaleAndPanRecognizer({
    @required this.onPanDown,
    @required this.onPanUpdate,
    @required this.onPanEnd,
  });

  int numPointers = 0;
  int timeFrame = 1;
  int pointer1;
  int pointer2;
  var time1;
  var time2;
  var position1;

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    print(numPointers);
    if (numPointers == 0) {
      pointer1 = event.pointer;
      print(pointer1);
      position1 = event.localPosition;
      manager.hold(pointer1); //hold the assignment for this pointer for now
      startTrackingPointer(pointer1);

      numPointers += 1;
      time1 = DateTime.now();
    } else if (numPointers == 1) {
      pointer2 = event.pointer;
      print(pointer2);
      resolvePointer(pointer2, GestureDisposition.rejected);
      time2 = DateTime.now();
      var diff = time2.difference(time1);
      print(diff);
      if (diff <= Duration(seconds: timeFrame)) {
        manager.release(pointer1);
        resolvePointer(pointer1, GestureDisposition.rejected);
      } else {
        resolvePointer(pointer1, GestureDisposition.accepted);
        manager.release(pointer1);
        onPanDown(position1);
      }
      numPointers = 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      onPanUpdate(event.localPosition);
    }
    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      onPanEnd();
      stopTrackingPointer(event.pointer);
    }
  }

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'only one pointer recognizer';

  @override
  void didStopTrackingLastPointer(int pointer) {}

}
```

Comment: I am on a similar journey. Right now my solution is to take the InteractiveViewer: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b429ec1e8fd737abd58501591e4b6c6f708bfb81/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/interactive_viewer.dart
There are some demos as well: https://github.com/justinmc/flutter-interactive-viewer-demos/commits?author=justinmc&since=2020-04-01&until=2020-04-28

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to replace `onPanUpdate, onPanEnd...` with `onScaleUpdate, onScaleEnd...`. Then just instead of `details.globalPosition`  use `details.focalPoint`. You will get the same behaviour as Pan, plus you will now have access to `details.scale` or `details.rotation`. Here is an example.

Before:

```
onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details){
              newPosition = details.globalPosition;
              //scale and rotation missing in pan
            },
```

After:

```
onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details){
              newPosition = details.focalPoint;
              newRotation = details.rotation;
              newScale = details.scale;
              //scale and rotation now available
            },
```

Hope this helps. Took me some time to figure it out too.

Answer (score 1):

Using Listener widget for listen pointer event, then handle pointer event to detect scale and pan gesture as you need.

- 1 pointer (down and up in short interval time) => Tap
- 1 pointer (down and up in long interval time) => Double Tap
- 1 pointer (down and moving) => Pan
- 2 pointer => scale and rotate

you can using [gesture_x_detector](https://pub.dev/packages/gesture_x_detector) for full support gestures(tap, double tap, scale, rotate, long press,..) together.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need pan when you want use scale
there is a properti on scale => pointerCount

```
if(details.pointerCount == 2){
//we have two finger so we can scale the widget
}else if(details.pointerCount == 1){
//we have one finger so we can do the move or something like we uses in pan 
}
```